# Gmsh Mesh generating

Tags: 3d, mesh, gmsh

I would like to ask for some help with my specific 3D meshing task.
I have attached a picture below where I tried to explain the rules I need to follow by meshing.
I would like to create it with the script language of Gmsh (In a '.geo' file).

The rules are written on the picture but I explain them too in this text:

- I would like to create a mesh of a cube that has one or more regular hollow spherical shells inside.
- The six sides of the cube must be coincident with respect to the spatial position of the nodes, whichever way you rotate the cube.
- The matrix material between the outer wall of the sphere and the sides of the cube must be filled with tetrahedrons.
- The wall of the spherical shell should be constructed with hexahedrons.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGXei.jpg)

I know that this is a very complex meshing task but I hope I can find some help here.

Thank you so much for your help!

I trie the same problem is 2D and it was a succes but is 3D I couldn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.